# Toggle Checkbox jQuery with onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 groups of textboxes

```
<div id="createPackage" style="display:block; text-align:left">
     <strong>Select Grade(s)</strong><a href="#" onclick="checkunCheckAll('grade')"><span id="selectAllgrade">Select All</span></a>
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="grade" value="2">
           <label for="2" class="label-normal">Grade 2</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="grade" value="3">
           <label for="3" class="label-normal">Grade 3</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="grade" value="4">
           <label for="4" class="label-normal">Grade 4</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="grade" value="5">
           <label for="5" class="label-normal">Grade 5</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="grade" value="6">
           <label for="6" class="label-normal">Grade 6</label>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
  <strong>Select Subject(s)</strong><a href="#" onclick="checkunCheckAll('grade')"><span id="selectAllsubject">Select All</span></a>
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td class="td-left-spacing">
           <input type="checkbox" id="ela" name="subject" value="ela">
           <label for="ela" class="label-normal">ELA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-right-spacing">
           <input type="checkbox" id="math" name="subject" value="math">
           <label for="math" class="label-normal">Math</label>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create Package(s)" class="center">
</div>
```

I wrote checkbox toggling in Javascript

```
    function checkunCheckAll(name) {
    var check =  document.getElementById("selectAll" + name).innerHTML == "Select All"

    var arrMarkMail = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrMarkMail.length; i++) {
        arrMarkMail[i].checked = check;
    }
    if (check)
    {
        document.getElementById("selectAll" + name).innerHTML = "Unselect All";
        document.getElementById("selectAll" + name).textContent = "Unselect All";
    }
    else
    {   
        document.getElementById("selectAll" + name).innerHTML = "Select All";
        document.getElementById("selectAll" + name).textContent = "Select All";
    }
}
```

But I would like to implement the "Select All" toggle similar to here

http://jsfiddle.net/NogginBox/ScnQT/1/

However, I want to change the text of that span to say "Unselect All" if they are all checked. I also want to be able to programatically check if at least one checkbox in each group is checked, and if it is, show the submit button at the bottom, hiding if that condition is not meant. What is the easiest way to do this in jQuery? I don't want to have to set the onchange of each checkbox individually if I do not have to.

Comment: I have the toggling in simple javascript, however, the hiding of the submit box gets a bit involved and I want the cleanest looking code possible. I have added my js to the question.

Comment: @IsaacLevin: This is unrelated to your issue, but please keep in mind that element IDs starting with numbers are technically "illegal" according to the HTML specification.

Comment: @Cory sure I can change that as part of cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by something along the lines of:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='grade'], input[type='checkbox'][name='subject']").on('change', function () {
     //do stuff
     var gradeCheckboxGroupChecked = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='grade']:checked"), 
         gradeCheckboxGroup = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='grade']");
     if (gradeCheckboxGroupChecked.length == gradeCheckboxGroup.length && same for the subject) {
        // or you can check for gradeCheckboxGroupChecked.not(':checked').length == 0 && subjectCheckbox.not(':checked').length == 0 instead
        //do what you need if all are selected
     } else if (gradeCheckboxGroupChecked.length > 0 || same for the subject) {
       // do actions for if atleast one is selected
     }
});
```

My solution is part pseudo code, appologies, it was a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('[type=submit]').hide()
$("#selectAllsubject,#selectAllgrade").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
    $(this).next().find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', 'checked')
  } else {
    $(this).next().find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', '')
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('checked')
  if ($('[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
    $('[type=submit]').show()
  } else {
    $('[type=submit]').hide()
  }
});

$('[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if ($('[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
    $('[type=submit]').show()
  } else {
    $('[type=submit]').hide()
  }
})
```

**[Working Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k47owkuh/5/)**

Comment: This does the toggling, but doesn't handle hiding the submit box

Comment: I did not get you. When do you need to hide / show the submit?

Comment: When at least one item in each group is checked. It also doesn't change the text of the spans to be "Unselect or Select"

Comment: @IsaacLevin I have updated my answer. Does that meet your need? `:-)`

Comment: Sort of, it still needs some tweaking, but I can work with it. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. It may help others also

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    updaeLabelText();
});

var checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(#checkAll)")
checkboxes.change(function () { 
 var checked = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', (checked >= checkboxes.length)? true: false); 
    updaeLabelText();
});

function updaeLabelText () {
 $("#checkAll").parent().contents().last()[0].textContent = $("#checkAll").is(':checked')? ' Uncheck all' : ' Check all';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```